# Resize Cancel Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm normally in Angular / Cordova world, but now im pressured to edit a native plugin, which im using with Cordova.

Source of the plugin
https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/ios

Can anyone explain me how I have to edit the files to manipulate the size of the cancel button.

**scannerOverlay.xib**

```
     <object class="IBUINavigationItem" id="240626599">
        <reference key="IBUINavigationBar" ref="1064216609"/>
            <string key="IBUITitle">Barcode Scanner</string>
            <object class="IBUIBarButtonItem" key="IBUILeftBarButtonItem" id="1053701234">
                <string key="IBUITitle">Cancel</string>
                <string key="targetRuntimeIdentifier">IBCocoaTouchFramework</string>
                <int key="IBUIStyle">1</int>
                <reference key="IBUINavigationItem" ref="240626599"/>
      </object>
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit the source XML of XIB files or storyboards. It's better to open them with Xcode and the interface builder. If your button is a native navigation item, you can't set its size explicitly. You should use a custom button.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But im new here. Which file I have to open with xcode?

Comment: You can open `scannerOverlay.xib`directly in Xcode.

Comment: Okay, that worked. But I have no Idea, when I create a new Button that it is linked with the "Cancel Function". Could you help me more? Thanks in advance.